# Render Bitmap for a given Rect

Tags: android, bitmap, rendering, rect

I'm trying to figure out how to build a `Bitmap` the size of a given `Rect`. I can generate the Bitmap independently (as displayed below), but I'm not familiar enough with the Android SDK to know what libraries to look into and how these two classes relate.

How do the Rect right/top/left/bottom properties relate to a Bitmap's size? Are these in pixels?

```
public Bitmap renderFragment(Rect rect){
    // step 1: collect underpants
    Bitmap fullBitmap = getBitmap();

    // step 2: ...
    Bitmap fragment = /* do some magic */

    // step 3: profit
    return fragment;
}

private Bitmap getBitmap()
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String imageUrl = "http://developer.android.com/design/media/creative_vision_main.png";
    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
    return bitmap;
}


public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have orginal bitmap, create a new a bitmap using with orginal bitmap. First you should create bounds of bitmap.

```
   Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap orginalBitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height) // This is part of orginal bitmap
   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap orginalBitmap, int destWidth, int destHeight, boolean filter ) // Create new bitmap
```

Be carefull about out of memory...